# add NULL to terminate double pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, null

I want to read vector array and covert this to double pointer to pass on the other c method. I tried this but I didn't get success for this code.
It's giving me wrong value like "" or any garbage value.

```
   std::vector<std::string> vec = {"Monday", "Tuesday"};

    char ** cstrings = new char * [vec.size()];
```

**Convert to double pointer (pointer to pointer)**

Reading time information need to terminate array, I know, I need to add the NULL value "\b" . But I didn't get success to add this.

```
                for (size_t i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i) {

                    printf("value of i %d \n",i);

                    cstrings[i] = new char[vec[i].size()+1];

                    std::strcat(cstrings[i],vec[i].c_str());

                    if(i==vec.size()){

                        printf("value of i %d \n",i);

                        cstrings[i+1] = new char[vec[i].size()+1];
                         std::strcat(cstrings[i+1],"/b");

                    }

                }
```

**Read Value of the Pointer**

Reading the double pointer loop, terminate when receive Null value. I didn't get success into this as well.

```
                for(char **p = cstrings; *p != NULL; ++p){
    
                    if( strcmp(*p,"/b") != 0) {

                        char * temp = *p;

                        printf(" Read value >> Days >>> %s \n",temp);
   
                    }

                }
```

**Out Put :**

```
Read value >> Days >>> Monday 
Read value >> Days >>> Tuesday
Read value >> Days >>>            // need to terminate for loop for this.
```

Comment: The `strcat` function assumes that the destination "string" is a null-terminated string. When you `new[]` the data for the string, the memory is not initialized and its contents will be *indeterminate*, leading to *undefined behavior* when `strcat` tries to find the terminator. Use `strcpy` instead.

Comment: Also note that inside the loop the condition `i==vec.size()` will *never* be true. And that if you change the loop condition then `i` will be *out of bounds*.

Comment: Also `"/b"` is not the same as `"\b"`. And `"\b"` is a string containing a single *backspace* character. Looking at the second snippet, you should make `cstrings[i]` equal to a *null pointer* not an empty string. Which of course means you should allocate `vec.size()+1` elements for `cstrings`.

Comment: If you want to stay out of the business of manual memory allocation when specifying `char **` elements to a function, [this question / answer may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669797/wrong-types-involving-converting-a-vector-to-feed-to-execvp)

Comment: A "double pointer" is not a thing in C++. What you're playing with here is a "pointer to pointer".

Answer (score 0):

Use strncpy instead of strcat. And specify the size.

```
 cstrings[i] = new char[vec[i].size()+1];
 std::strcat(cstrings[i],vec[i].c_str());
```

should be replaced with:

```
 cstrings[i] = new char[vec[i].size()+1];
 std::strncpy(cstrings[i], vec[i].c_str(), vec[i].size());
 cstrings[i][vec[i].size()] = '\0';
```

A simpler approach would be to use the C function strdup:

```
cstrings[i] = strdup(vec[i].c_str() );
```

Comment: Actually, the char* returned by c_str() is guaranteed to be null-terminated.

see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str

"Returns a pointer to a null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string. "

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. The reason I thought that was from the undefined behavior of writing to c_str.